# MySQL get rows not present in relation table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, many-to-many

Practice -> Financier (Many to Many)

Practice -> Financier_Practice (Many to one).

```
Practice

practice_id
practice_name


Financier

financier_id
financier_name


Financier_Practice

financier_id
practice_id
enabled
```

I have some records in `financier_practice`, now I want to get all `practices` that are not yet assigned to a given financier.

Example, if I have 3 practices, and one assigned to a `financier`, then return the other two for the same financier.

What should I do?

I thought `LEFT JOIN` would do it, first selecting practices, but it would return all practices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*
FROM Practice p
LEFT JOIN Financier_Practice fp
    ON p.practice_id = fp.practice_id
WHERE fp.practice_id IS NULL AND
      fp.financier_id = 3     -- replace 3 with whatever value you want
```

Comment: Where do you set the financier_id here?

Comment: Thanks, I've used the AND condition in the left join, is it the same?

Comment: I've discovered that my original JOIN wasn't working because I was doing WHERE x = NULL instead WHERE x IS NULL

Comment: I don't think it matters where we put the financier ID check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `cross join` to generate all the rows and then some method to remove the ones that exist.  The following uses `left join`:

```
select f.financier_id, p.practice_id
from financier f cross join
     practice p left join
     financier_practice fp
     on fp.financier_id = f.financier_id and fp.practie_id = p.practice_id
where fp.financier_id is null;
```